# Why does code works in multiple "online c compilers" and sometimes in clion, but doesnt in VS?

Tags: c, visual-c++, output, clion

My problem is, that first print in Clion is everytime correct, then 2nd and 3rd are bad values and then again, output is correct. I decided to hand the task, because i thought Clion was just glitching, as i tested the code in few "online c compilers" and it worked fine.

The task was about to count and print the movement (+ / - ) of food from included code.
Photo:

1. [Correct output in Clion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Izq.jpg)
2. [Incorrect output in Clion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zQjR.jpg)
3. [VS output - teacher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO3wz.jpg)
4. [My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nNz1.jpg)
5. [Code included in "my code"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oml3N.jpg)
6. my code:

```
`typedef enum { kus=1,kg } Jednotka;
typedef union { int kus; float kg; } Mnozstvi;
typedef enum { rohlik,chleb,brambory,sirup,merunky,cukr,cokolada,salam,mleko,kava,pivo,mouka,maso,sul,kmin,fazole,meloun } Potravina;
typedef struct { Potravina potr; Jednotka jedn; Mnozstvi mnoz; } Pohyb;

const Pohyb pohyb[]={{chleb,kg,{.kg=20}},{cukr,kg,{.kg=10}},{rohlik,kus,{.kus=70}},{cokolada,kus,{.kus=15}},{kava,kg,{.kg=2}},{mouka,kg,{.kg=5}},
                     {salam,kg,{.kg=6.5}},{mleko,kus,{.kus=30}},{brambory,kg,{.kg=40}},{merunky,kg,{.kg=8}},{sirup,kus,{.kus=18}},{mouka,kg,{.kg=5}},
                     {cukr,kg,{.kg=-1.5}},{cokolada,kus,{.kus=-2}},{brambory,kg,{.kg=-5}},{rohlik,kus,{.kus=-10}},{pivo,kus,{.kus=10}},
                     {kmin,kg,{.kg=.06}},{fazole,kg,{.kg=5}},{chleb,kg,{.kg=-1}},{mleko,kus,{.kus=-2}},{sirup,kus,{.kus=-1}},{pivo,kus,{.kus=25}},
                     {kava,kg,{.kg=6.5}},{mouka,kg,{.kg=-4}},{fazole,kg,{.kg=-.5}},{cukr,kg,{.kg=-2}},{cokolada,kus,{.kus=-3}},{sul,kg,{.kg=6}},
                     {brambory,kg,{.kg=-3.5}},{merunky,kg,{.kg=-.5}},{sirup,kus,{.kus=-3}},{mouka,kg,{.kg=5}},{pivo,kus,{.kus=-1}},
                     {mouka,kg,{.kg=-2}},{maso,kg,{.kg=10}},{maso,kg,{.kg=5.5}},{rohlik,kus,{.kus=-4}},{chleb,kg,{.kg=-3}},{rohlik,kus,{.kus=-35}},
                     {sirup,kus,{.kus=5}},{cokolada,kus,{.kus=-2}},{salam,kg,{.kg=-.3}},{merunky,kg,{.kg=-3}},{maso,kg,{.kg=-.5}},{maso,kg,{.kg=-.8}},
                     {meloun,kg,{.kg=22.5}},{meloun,kg,{.kg=-3.2}},{chleb,kg,{.kg=-.5}},{sirup,kus,{.kus=-1}},{mleko,kus,{.kus=-4}},{sul,kg,{.kg=-1}},
                     {rohlik,kus,{.kus=20}},{maso,kg,{.kg=-1.5}},{pivo,kus,{.kus=-8}}};

const unsigned POHYB=sizeof pohyb/sizeof *pohyb;

const char *nazev[]={"rohlik","chleb","brambory","sirup","merunky","cukr","cokolada","salam","mleko","kava","pivo","mouka","maso","sul","kmin","fazole","meloun"};

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int pocetPotravin = sizeof nazev / sizeof nazev[0]; // 17
    typedef struct {
        Potravina nazev;
        float myMnz;
        Jednotka myJedn;
    } vysPohyb;
    vysPohyb vyspohyb[pocetPotravin];
    for (int i = 0; i < pocetPotravin; ++i) {
        vyspohyb[i].nazev = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < POHYB; ++i) {
        if (pohyb[i].jedn == 2) {
            vyspohyb[pohyb[i].potr].myMnz = vyspohyb[pohyb[i].potr].myMnz + pohyb[i].mnoz.kg;
            vyspohyb[pohyb[i].potr].myJedn = pohyb[i].jedn;
        }
        else {
            vyspohyb[pohyb[i].potr].myMnz = vyspohyb[pohyb[i].potr].myMnz + pohyb[i].mnoz.kus;
            vyspohyb[pohyb[i].potr].myJedn = pohyb[i].jedn;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < pocetPotravin; ++i) {
        if (vyspohyb[i].myJedn == 2) {
            printf("%s %g kg \n", nazev[vyspohyb[i].nazev], vyspohyb[i].myMnz);
        }
        else {
            printf("%s %g ks \n", nazev[vyspohyb[i].nazev], vyspohyb[i].myMnz);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the code in c compilers online, and on my friend's pc.

Comment: Turn off permissive mode, and gcc will tell you that converting an int to an enum is not allowed.

Comment: this is C not C++, right? In c++ it wouldnt compile

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: If you want others to understand what your program is doing, consider using English words for the identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vysPohyb vyspohyb[pocetPotravin];
```

This array is not initialised, values of its elements are indeterminate.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pocetPotravin; ++i) {
    vyspohyb[i].nazev = i;
}
```

This loop assigns a value to one field of each element, leaving two other fields uninitialised (i.e. garbage).

```
vyspohyb[pohyb[i].potr].myMnz = vyspohyb[pohyb[i].potr].myMnz + pohyb[i].mnoz.kg;
        vyspohyb[pohyb[i].potr].myJedn = pohyb[i].jedn;
```

This uses garbage values from the uninitialised fields.

Unfortunately the usual tools are not very good at catching this error. The sanitizer library [misses it altogether](https://godbolt.org/z/x9Pe7WozY), whereas valgrind reports "Use of uninitialised value of size 8" deep inside `printf`, i.e. far away from the first actual use of an uninitialised value. Still, at least valgrind gives you a hint.